# How to choose correct flags and attributes

Tags: android

I've been reading quit a lot on the subject and I'm still confused. In order to apply the correct flags and attributes to my application I need confirmation on the mental picture I have right now.

Can / will someone please conform or falsify following statement:

1.
A device runs multiple applications; true.

2.
An application contains multiple activities; true.

3.
An application holds one and only one stack (back-stack or task); true.

4.
An activity can (but not must) run in multiple applications, so the activitu in question can be part of multiple but very different stacks; true.

5.
Stack, back-stack and task are just different words for one and the same thing; true.

If false please explaine.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you list is more or less true except for your understanding of "application". This applies to statements 1, 2 and 3 and 4.

In Android, an **application** represents a package of **components (ie: activities, broadcast receivers, services and content providers)** that are stored together. During runtime, the concept of **application** is pretty loose, and only relevant regarding security and permissions (which **components** can access which other components and data). Android doesn't **run applications**.

When a user starts an **application**, what really happens is that Android launches a single **activity** into (usually) a new **task** or an existing **task** (Note: this is a simplification, there are certain cases where a new activity isn't created).

Android runs **components**, and the **components** run inside a Virutal Machine (VM) inside a **process**. A **process** is an OS entity.

In Android, a **task** is a sequence of activities that are started and are bound together. A **task** may contain activities from multiple **applications**, or may contain activities all from the same **application**. The **activities** within a **task** are in a specific sequence and this is referred to as the **task stack, activity stack, back stack or just stack**. These **activities** can be running all in the same **process**, or they can be running in different **processes**. It is important to understand that a **task** and a **process** and an **application** are very different things.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you! It would be nice, handy and above all very educational if Android documentation makes this clear. Thanks again.